# SQL: How to limit the number of records the MERGE statement will insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, filter

Some sample data:

```
DECLARE @TARGET TABLE ( ID INT, value INT ) ;
DECLARE @SOURCE TABLE ( ID INT, value INT )

INSERT INTO @TARGET VALUES ( 1, 213 )             
INSERT INTO @TARGET VALUES ( 2, 3 )             
INSERT INTO @TARGET VALUES ( 3, 310 )             
INSERT INTO @TARGET VALUES ( 4, 43 )                     

INSERT INTO @SOURCE VALUES ( 1, 134 )             
INSERT INTO @SOURCE VALUES ( 2, 34 )             
INSERT INTO @SOURCE VALUES ( 13, 310 )             
INSERT INTO @SOURCE VALUES ( 14, 43 )             
INSERT INTO @SOURCE VALUES ( 15,32 )             
INSERT INTO @SOURCE VALUES ( 16, 30 )             
INSERT INTO @SOURCE VALUES ( 17, 60 )             
INSERT INTO @SOURCE VALUES ( 18, 5 )                   


MERGE @TARGET t USING (SELECT * FROM @SOURCE) AS s ON (t.id = s.id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES (s.id,s.value);

SELECT * FROM @TARGET
```

So I'm having a target table , and a source table. What I want to accomplish is that when there is a large number of `not matched` items, to only insert the x top items with the highest value.
Using top on the merge itself won't work, because that would limit the whole source table, I want to do something like

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
LIMIT(5) AND ORDER BY Value DESC --only insert the 5 non-matches with the highest value
INSERT VALUES (s.id,s.value)
```

---- UPDATE ----
My MERGE statement also contains an WHEN MATCHED THEN statement:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET t.value = s.value
```

this sadly negates the answers given by Ian and Dog...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't SET ROWCOUNT Deprecated, you could use the top clause if you do it like this:

```
;MERGE TOP (5) @TARGET t USING 
(SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT * FROM @SOURCE ORDER BY VALUE DESC) AS s ON (t.id = s.id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN
INSERT VALUES (s.id,s.value);

SELECT * FROM @TARGET
```

The ORDER BY int the merge wont work unless you have a TOP Clause so using TOP (100) PERCENT tricks SQL into allowing the ordering.

Edit:

What about doing it in two steps?

```
;MERGE TOP (5) @TARGET t USING 
(SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT * FROM @SOURCE ORDER BY VALUE DESC) AS s ON (t.id = s.id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN
INSERT VALUES (s.id,s.value);/*
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET t.value = s.value;*/

update t 
set t.Value = s.Value
from     @Target t
    join @Source s on t.ID = s.ID 
where t.Value <> s.Value

SELECT * FROM @TARGET
```

Comment: you are right about the SET ROWCOUNT being deprecated. 
In my comment to Ian Quigley I wrote that my example is oversimplified, and left out the fact that I also have an WHEN MATCHED THEN statement which updates the target. The update should happen on all matched records, the insert should only ...

Comment: ... happen on the top x records with the highest value. 
Your example would work if I wouldn't have the other requirement.

Comment: What about doing it in two steps see amended answer.

Comment: I also thought about doing it like that. seems like that is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SET ROWCOUNT n;`

For example;

```
SET ROWCOUNT 4;
UPDATE Production.ProductInventory
SET Quantity = 400
WHERE Quantity < 300;
```

See; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Or you can do

```
Insert to @Target 
Select top 5 s.id, s.value from @Source s 
order by s.value desc ... etc.
```

Comment: I wrote a comment before stackoverflow crashed... and erased this comment , and some other comments on other questions :-(

anyway I oversimplified the example, there is also a WHEN MATCHED THEN, which should always update. Using the rowcount, it would first do the WHEN MATCHED and if there are ...

Comment: ... less rows updated then stated in the rowcount, it will INSERT in the WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN. 
This is not what I want, I want to limit only the INSERT and not the UPDATEs

Comment: Not familiar with "murge", I would think about doing "where s.id not in (select id from @source). You could even do that with a trick join where the right hand side is null..Meh.. :)